# list adapter with sections

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I already have a list adapter that works properly. But I want to divide the object in the list into sections according to the date they were created. Something like this:

[image]

I found something called "sectioned recycler view" but couldn't find any documentation on that. I read all the related questions, but they all are either outdated or use a third-party library. What's the native way of implementing this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you could use. First the easy one:

- make the header part of your item layout, but with `GONE` visibility by default
- in `onBindViewHolder`, decide whether the header should be `VISIBLE` or `GONE`

The logic there depends on what you want, but it could be as simple as

```
val visible = position == 0 || items[position].date != items[position - 1].date
```

Basically you just need to work out what the condition is that would cause an item to be in a different "group" than the previous item, and then if it's met, show the header over that item.

---

The approach *MarkL* is talking about is more complex, but it's also more robust - by having separate `Item` and `Header` elements, you can treat them differently, and even do stuff like having the header collapse/show its children, select them all etc. You can do that with the other approach, but it requires more code since you're not *really* treating things as groups, it's more of a trick when it comes to displaying stuff.

Basically, ignoring the how for now, you need a list of headers and items. A sealed class is a good way to represent that:

```
sealed class ListElement {
    data class Header(val date: Date) : ListElement()
    data class Item(val itemData: YourItem) : ListElement()
}
```

I've made `Item` a wrapper class that holds your actual data object inside, since that's probably coming from elsewhere and you can't define it as part of this sealed class hierarchy - so sticking it inside one of the subclasses like this allows you to do that.

So now you can have a `List<ListElement>` containing `Header`s and `Item`s in display order. Since you've mentioned creating the `ViewHolder`s in a comment I won't explain all that, but basically when you're getting the item type for a position, you just need to check `is Header` or `is Item` and then handle it from there.

---

As for creating that list, there are lots of ways to do it - you could use [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) to generate a `Map` of dates to lists of items, map each of those entries to a list of `Header, Item, Item...`, and flatten the whole thing into a single list:

```
items.map { Item(it) }
    .groupBy { it.itemData.date }
    .entries
    .flatMap { (date, items) -> listOf(Header(date)) + items }
```

The advantage with a map like this is it's an actual grouped structure, so you can keep it around to generate flat lists for display - e.g. hiding a group's contents by only including the header in the list.

Or you could just build the list yourself, similar to the logic I mentioned in the first example - if the date has changed from the previous item, insert a `Header` first:

```
val list = mutableListOf<ListElement>().apply {
    for (item in items) {
        // add a header if the date changed - this handles the first header
        // in an empty list too (where lastOrNull returns null, so the date is null)
        val previousItemDate = (lastOrNull() as? Item)?.itemData?.date
        if (previousItemDate != item.date) add(Header(item.date))
        add(Item(item))
    }
}
```

Or you could use `fold`. Don't forget to sort stuff!

Comment: first of all, thanks for such an extensive answer! I really appreciate it. I decided to use the first approach as the rest is a bit complicated for me. thank you so much, it solved my problem))

Comment: @jane no worries! The second answer's more about wrangling your list into actual groups of objects, or a list where the headers and items are both included but as separate elements. That gives you more options and control, but if you don't need that then no need to overcomplicate things!

Answer (score 2):

You could create 2 types of view holders:

1. header which holds the date
2. data container which holds the other information.

And then create a list of objects which contain something like this:
listToBind = (header, data, data, header, data, data)

For your case, where header & info is the same object, you can do something like this:

take your object you receive from backend (example)
YourObject(val header: String, val info:InfoObject)

create 2 display objects, both inheriting from a type that your adapter accepts (say - AdapterDisplayEntity)
HeaderDisplayEntity(val header: String): AdapterDisplayEntity
InfoDisplayEntity(val info: InfoObject): AdapterDisplayEntity

now you can use your list that contains these items and submit to your adapter.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i didn't understand listToBind part tho

Comment: I meant "listToBind" as in the list that you will call in your "adapter.submitList(listToBind)" or whatever type of recycler that you are using where you notify the adapter with a new list to bind. hope this is clearer

Comment: the thing is I don't know what to do next after creating the view holders. header and information are in the same object. how can I write the logic so that if the objects' dateCreated is the same, they be under the same header?

Comment: Jane, i've updated my solution, hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Use nested recycler view for this instead. You can check the example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-nested-recyclerview-in-android/amp/).
Best solution for this scenario so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jetpack Compose you can use the [stickyHeader()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScope#stickyHeader(kotlin.Any,kotlin.Any,kotlin.Function1)) as documented in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists)

Comment: im using xml. thanks for the answer tho!